# Laravel Eloquent ORM exists property not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Using Laravel and Eloquent ORM, I'm trying to determine if a record exists in my database. This is the code I'm using to test things out:

```
$store = Store::where('ext_hash', 'thisHashExists')->first();
if($store->exists){
        echo 'yes';
}
else{
        echo 'no';
}

$another_store = Store::where('ext_hash', 'thisHashDoesNotExist')->first();
if($another_store->exists){
        echo 'yes';
}
else{
        echo 'no';
}
```

For the first example, where the hash exists, it works correctly, but in the second example, when the hash does not exist, I receive an error on the `$another_store->exists` line.

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I'm guessing the error is because the $another_store object isn't actually an object since I attempted to create it with a static method. How is this `exists` property supposed to be used?

I tried creating the object first, then retrieving it with non-static methods, but the methods don't seem to work that way, unless I'm missing something.  For example:

```
$store = new Store();
$store->where('id', 1)->first();
print_r($store);
```

That code just prints an empty `Store` object, as if the `where` and `first` methods had no effect on it.  Is that expected?

Comment: First() return values are the Model object or null. If there is no value within the results null is returned.

Comment: Ok thanks. So to check if the record exists I can just check that the variable is not null. What about the last part of my question using methods like `where` on an already instantiated object. Should that correctly retrieve an object or can the methods not be used that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Eloquent` has a nice method `firstOrFail()`, which throws `ModelNotFoundException` if your request doesn't return a proper row. After, you can either do a standart `try-catch`, or register an error handler via `App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e){ Response::make('model not found'); })`.

Also, you can use `firstOrNew()` to get a new instance of your model if it isn't found by your request.

And if you want to keep your code as simple as possible, you can just check with `instanceof Eloquent`.

As for your error - `first` returns an object, it doesn't hydrate its caller, so your code would work if you'd do this:

```
$store = new Store();
$foundStore = $store->where('id', 1)->first();
print_r($foundStore);
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know about the last part of my question using methods like `where` on an already instantiated object. Should that correctly retrieve an object or can the methods not be used that way? I'm asking because I would like to assign fillable properties at instance level, so I need to create the instance before using firstOrNew, since the properties I pass to firstOrNew will trigger a mass assignment exception.

Comment: Actually, you may pass properties to `firstOrNew()` as an array like this: `$user = User::firstOrNew(array('name' => 'John'));`. You can also instantly save an object into a database with: `$user = User::firstOrCreate(array('name' => 'John'));`

Comment: Yes, but I was getting a mass assignment exception if I passed in multiple values to firstOrCreate. How can I avoid that without adding fillable properties on the class level?

Comment: I'm not sure i can help you without seeing your code. Anyways, that's another question whatsoever.